# C LNK2011 and LNK2019 error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2005, linker-errors

I write this below code in VS2005:

```
#include <posapi.h>
#include <posapi_all.h>
#include <arabic_farsi_api.h>
#include <arabic_farsi_deprecated.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "paxarfa.lib")

const APPINFO AppInfo={
    "POS-Simple example",
    "APP-TEST",
    "1.0",
    "pcteam",
    "demo program",
    "",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    ""
};

int event_main(ST_EVENT_MSG *msg)
{
    SystemInit();
    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    SystemInit();

    ArPrintString(AR_ALIGN_CENTER, "HI");

    return 0;
}
```

also add `paxarfa.lib` in project *properties->Linker->Input* and set lib path to *C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories*, also use `pragma` to define `paxarfa.lib`, but `LNK 2019` and `LNK2011` happened in ArPrintString function..

Code is in C, not in C++.

I want to show arabic char and must use `paxarfa.lib` and `arabic_farsi_api.h` and `arabic_farsi_deprecated.h` to show arabic char.

Comment: I never worked on VS, but just asking, what about the path to the header? Did you add that, too?

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do? Is there an error?

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes add in project properties, i forced to write code in vs.

Comment: @MeanGreen I develop app in pax devices. want to show arabic char and must use `paxarfa.lib` and `arabic_farsi_api.h` and `arabic_farsi_deprecated.h` to show arabic char.

Comment: @1mohammadi.ir then please update your question and add that information :)